# Preserve stdout after os/exec.Cmd.Wait()

Tags: go, process, stdout

I'm working with os/exec, sending input and receiving output as a command runs.
I need to store the command's return code when it finishes, so I have a goroutine with `err := cmd.Wait()`, and I get any failure return code from the err.
But Wait() seems to throw away the remaining stdout which I need also.
So how do I preserve the remaining stdout of a os/exec.Cmd after Cmd.Wait()?

Example code, using the Unix bc calculator command:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
    "bufio"
    "io"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-c", "bc")
    stdin, _ := cmd.StdinPipe()
    stdout, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
    cmd.Start()

    go func() {
        cmd.Wait()
        fmt.Println("finished")
    }()

    io.WriteString(stdin, "1 + 2\n")
    fmt.Println(scanner.Scan(), scanner.Text())
    io.WriteString(stdin, "3 + 4\n")
    fmt.Println(scanner.Scan(), scanner.Text())
    io.WriteString(stdin, "5 + 6\n")
    io.WriteString(stdin, "quit\n")  // cmd.Wait() runs
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    // Prints false :(
    fmt.Println(scanner.Scan(), scanner.Text())
}
```

This prints:
true 3
true 7
finished
false

I'd like:
true 3
true 7
finished
true 11

I also tried setting cmd.Stdout to a bytes.Buffer like:

```
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdout = &buf
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(&buf)
```

But that was unreliable. It printed all false unless I added in delays with time.Sleep().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call cmd.Wait() after reading to the end of stdout.

Option 1: call cmd.Wait from the main goroutine after scanner.Scan() returns false.

```
cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-c", "bc")
stdin, _ := cmd.StdinPipe()
stdout, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
cmd.Start()

io.WriteString(stdin, "1 + 2\n")
fmt.Println(scanner.Scan(), scanner.Text())
io.WriteString(stdin, "3 + 4\n")
fmt.Println(scanner.Scan(), scanner.Text())
io.WriteString(stdin, "5 + 6\n")
io.WriteString(stdin, "quit\n") // cmd.Wait() runs
fmt.Println(scanner.Scan(), scanner.Text())
fmt.Println(scanner.Scan(), scanner.Text()) // prints false
cmd.Wait()
```

Option 2: read from the waiting goroutine:

```
cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-c", "bc")
stdin, _ := cmd.StdinPipe()
stdout, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
cmd.Start()

var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(1)
go func() {
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
    }
    cmd.Wait()
    defer wg.Done()
}()

io.WriteString(stdin, "1 + 2\n")
io.WriteString(stdin, "3 + 4\n")
io.WriteString(stdin, "5 + 6\n")
io.WriteString(stdin, "quit\n") // cmd.Wait() runs
wg.Wait()
```